# Multilevel Relationship in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have three tables and i want to make multiple relationship between then
orders,order_details,book

[image]

I want to make a common relation between then to take values in a single array .I am using following Code

**Order.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table='orders';

    public function orderDetails(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail','order_id');
    }
}
```

**OrderDetail.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderDetail extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table='order_details';

    public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }

    public function book(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }

}
```

and **Book.php**

```
public function orderDetail(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\OrderDetail','App\Book','id','item');
    }
```

where item is foreign key and primary key in book table

in **OrderController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order,App\OrderDetail,App\Book,App\User;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function userOrders(){OrderDetail::find($orderId)->where('order_id',$orderId)->where('item','book.id')->get(); }
```

Comment: Could you tell us more about what's not working? What is the desired result and what is it that you're getting instead?